# Ligature glyph bearing rendered incorrectly - FontForge - OTF font

Tags: font-forge, opentype, ligatures

I'm trying to modify a Burmese font "Myanmar Text" using FontForge so that it displays Latin letters with Burmese ones. Everything is fine until I realise one of the ligatures (the ligature **ur_1 which** combine **U** and **R** into 1 single symbol) seems to have zero right bearing and hence leading to the overlapping of letters that follow it when tested in Word or any text editing software. I checked the bearing in FontForge and it's set to 58.

[image]

The Metric view is correct.

[image]

But when installed and used it looks like this:

[image]

I have checked the bearing multiple times it's set to 58. I have also tried removing all kerning info but to no avail. I have also tried other symbols in this glyph and using different glyphs for this ligature but it still the same. Other ligatures work fine except this one. Is it because of the name of the glyph? Anybody knows why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It’s very hard to figure out what exactly is going on where here, because your assignation of Burmese characters to Latin ones is quite hard to grasp (at least for someone who doesn’t know Burmese, as I don’t). As far as I can tell, the example you give here says _ŋìɲòdʲ_ in Burmese, and I can’t figure out exactly how that’s supposed to map to ‘tourists’. Also, zero right bearing wouldn’t be enough for the overlap shown – it looks like it has zero right bearing **and** zero width.

Answer (score 2):

Your `i.sign1` is getting -524 for `LBearing` and that will overlap back characters.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/108758)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/108757)

Comment: `i.sign1` is (I think) the circle on top of the ligature highlighted with the red border. It’s a combining diacritic, so it’s supposed to have zero width and a negative left bearing.